# Scala how to update values in immutable list

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a immutable list and need a new copy of it with elements replaced at multiple index locations.  The List.updated is an O(n) operation and can only replace one at a time.  What is the efficient way of doing this?  Thanks!

Comment: Using `Vector` (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector) instead of `List`.

Comment: BTW, prepending is O(1), so `List` can be efficient if you take care during the construction of lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`List` is not a good fit if you need random element access/update. From the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List):

> This class is optimal for last-in-first-out (LIFO), stack-like access patterns. If you need another access pattern, for example, random access or FIFO, consider using a collection more suited to this than `List`.

More generally, what you need is an indexed sequence instead of a linear one (such as `List`). From the documentation of [`IndexedSeq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq):

> Indexed sequences support constant-time or near constant-time element access and length computation. They are defined in terms of abstract methods apply for indexing and length.
>
> Indexed sequences do not add any new methods to `Seq`, but promise efficient implementations of random access patterns.

The default concrete implementation of `IndexedSeq` is [`Vector`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector), so you may consider using it.

Here's an extract from its documentation (emphasis added):

> Vector is a general-purpose, immutable data structure. **It provides random access and updates in effectively constant time**, as well as very fast append and prepend. Because vectors strike a good balance between fast random selections and fast random functional updates, they are currently the default implementation of immutable indexed sequences

Comment: That only matters for read access though.
Copy/update for an immutable collection will be O(n) regardless of whether it is random access or not.

Comment: *immutable* Vector?
Don't think so ... :)

Comment: @Dima yep! From the docs: *Vector is a general-purpose, immutable data structure. It provides random access and updates in effectively constant time*

Comment: @Dima The key point is that immutable data structures don't need to be pessimistically copied when returning a new version. You can reuse old unchanged chunks (say, the tail) since they are guaranteed not to change over time.

Answer (score -2):

```
list
    .iterator
    .zipWithIndex
    .map { case (index, element) => newElementFor(index) }
    .toList
```

Comment: This is still O(n), not an improvement.

Comment: Copying a collection is O(n). You can't do any better as long as it is immutable.

Comment: take a look at `Vector` it has better performance for most of the operations.